# Building up a frame

Tags: fixed-gear, build

I bought a Philips frame off Craigslist for $60, and decided I wanted to build a fixie out of it.  I have the frame and a quill stem so far.  The bottom bracket has to be replaced because I don't have the cranks for it, and it's pretty old and probably junk.

What can I expect the cost to be? Where can I cut corners for cost now, then upgrade later?

Am I insane for wanting to take on this task?  Should I cut losses and buy a good frame that's custom fitted for me if I want to build up a bike?

Comment: RE: Your last point; If the frame doesn't fit you, why bother?

Comment: I'm not sure if the frame fits, haha. I think it does, its hanging in my shed right now.  I meant custom fit

Comment: "custom fit" and "save money" are opposite things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of these questions have answers that are based on very subjective and personal choices.

Yes, you should look at buy a frame that fits, if this one doesn't fit.

No, I wouldn't build an old frame with new (even new old stock) parts, since the value of the complete build will be far less, generally, than you will spend on the parts to build it, and many of the parts will need to be replaced if you pick a new frame to rebuild everything on later.

Are you doing this as a learning project? If so, then the education might offset the extra cost involved. If you just want a fixie, fixies are cheap. I'll pretty much guarantee you can buy a better fixie than you can build, for around the same cost.

All of these are things you have to weigh the value of for you personally. I wouldn't do it. But then, I know that because I've done it. So how should I tell you not to do it?

Do it or don't, as long as you are aware it isn't the cost effective route, but it might be the fun, DIY route for you... If so, Enjoy it.